# Automate trigger from email that has been replied

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am new in VBA. I would like to ask on how to trigger email which has been reply.

Scenario : I have this coding as below which send the email to recipient (Column B) if there is "yes" in column C.

```
For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                        "your account up to date"
                'You can add files also like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display
            End With
```

Question : How can I trigger if the recipient has replied to my email that I sent earlier? I would like to automate the trigger to my excel file on column E as remark recipient has replied to my email. Ex, "replied / no reply".

Really appreciate for any help since I am new in VBA.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your using Microsoft Outlook and an Exchange Server.*

There are 3 Extended MAPI properties that deal with the message state for replied to/forwarded:

> PR_ICON_INDEX (0x10800003)
>   PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (0x10810003)
>   PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME (0x10820040)

This MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176395(office.12).aspx provides code that shows how to use these MAPI Properties:

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorGetProperty()
    Dim PropName, Header As String
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    'Get first item in the inbox
    Set oMail = _
        Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1)
    'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS
    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"
    'Obtain an instance of PropertyAccessor class
    Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor
    'Call GetProperty
    Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)
    Debug.Print (Header)
End Sub
```

You will want to replace the 'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS ie **0x007D001E** in the above code and I'm guessing you'll want to go through more than just the first mail item...